# Qual "status code" usar quando não há um um dado no corpo de uma requisição POST?

Tags: http-status

Estou criando uma aplicação para o cliente realizar o upload de um arquivo para o servidor e eu gostaria de saber qual o *Status Code* ideal para retornar caso na requisição o arquivo ou qualquer outro dado importante não seja enviado no *body*.

Veja esse exemplo abaixo:

```
{dado1: "3457", dado2: "0110xFC"} // Status Code: 200  (todos os dados são enviados)
```

---

```
{dado1: "3457"} // Status Code: ??? (faltou enviar o segundo dado)
```

Comment: `{dado:[{dado1:"3457", dado2:'0110xFC'}]}` Será tratar o Objeto +- desta maneira? Apenas estou usando a lógica, realmente não sou o "programador" quando se trata de JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se fez um request que não está válido, a reposta é do grupo 4xx.

Pode por exemplo ser um `400` *"Bad request"*, ou  *"Request inválido"*.

Mais detalhes dos erros 4xx podem ser vistos aqui: https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/